# IIS7 URL Rewrite, how to set to handle Friendly URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

Looking to get something working in II7 URL Rewriting i.e

product.aspx?id=200&name=Microsoft

to

product/200/Microsoft

I was following this tutorial 
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/

But basically that though me how to create a table with an old link and new link and to redirect to new link once the old urls is entered. Which is cool but not what I want.

I.e I need a REAL URL to go to a Friendly URL in IIS7 URL Rewrite

so i.e if the unfriendly URL is entered it redirects to friendly, and if friendly URL entered it stays as the URL but contains in the link the contents of the unfriendly URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT : Slight Change

Ok So the site I am working on right lists organisations, and each org has 5 different details pages. Overview,Purpose,Governance,Financial, and last one I cant remember but anyway. Each one has its own .aspx page. So I have overview.aspx,governance.aspx,financial.aspx . And I want to get friendly URL's set up for each section. So yes Each org would have 5 Friendly URLS. Now the Tricky part is I want the section name AFTER the org name. I.e /Orgname/Financial or /Microsoft/Governance. From looking at the samples its put template – StevieB 26 secs ago edit 
Ah yes I understand that now and here my very last question. Ok So the site I am working on right lists organisations, and each org has 5 different details pages. Overview,Purpose,Governance,Financial, and last one I cant remember but anyway. Each one has its own .aspx page. So I have overview.aspx,governance.aspx,financial.aspx . And I want to get friendly URL's set up for each section. So yes Each org would have 5 Friendly URLS. Now the Tricky part is I want the section name AFTER the org name. I.e /Orgname/Financial or /Microsoft/Governance. From looking at the samples its put template
    name first and then the querystring friendly URL, how can I switch this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the rewrite module 2.0 and when you double click the URL Rewrite icon you get to the settings page. Here you right-click and choose "Add Rule..."
On the dialog that gets opened there are several templates. If you look in the "Inbound and Outbound Rules" category you will see User-friendly URL.
I used that to automaticlly create exactly the kind of rule you are talking about. I entered my original URLs and it auto-generated exactly what you are looking for.
The big plus of this is that it not only re-writes incoming requests, but also re-writes links on outgoing responses. So if you have a link to product.aspx?id=200&name=Microsoft on the page, it will convert the link (the html itself) to point to product/200/Microsoft.
Very handy and works GREAT! :)
[image]

Comment: Tried it out and made a screenshot for ya. Just wrote the original link and it generated the new one automaticaly.

Comment: Elad, thats awesome, thanks for that and works great. But I just realised, I need a slight different solution. Ideally I would have i.e Real Url product.aspx?id=200 and then actual URL product/Microsoft. So I would have to a DB look up to match the ID and Name. Is this best done with a mapping file or so ?

Comment: When your request is passed to the ISAPI asp.net engine, it is translated to the query string. Your code-behind will see the query string. That's the point :)

Comment: Ah yes I understand that now and here my very last question. Ok So the site I am working on right lists organisations, and each org has 5 different details pages. Overview,Purpose,Governance,Financial, and last one I cant remember but anyway. Each one has its own .aspx page. So I have overview.aspx,governance.aspx,financial.aspx . And I want to get friendly URL's set up for each section. So yes Each org would have 5 Friendly URLS. Now the Tricky part is I want the section name AFTER the org name. I.e  /Orgname/Financial  or /Microsoft/Governance. From looking at the samples its put template

Comment: name first and then the querystring friendly URL, how can I switch this ?

Comment: You see the dropdownlist? You can choose from about four or five different schemes it creates for you. One of them might be good for you. If not, you can create the rule from the template and then edit the regex to fit your needs.

Comment: i.e. it creates a base regex for you, which you can later move around.

Comment: Aye I saw the dropdown list there was no example with the template .aspx page friendly name coming after the querystring. The Regex seems disabled how could I edit it ?

Comment: You can edit the regex AFTER you create the rule, but this template takes alot of the guess work out of it.

Comment: I.e I the following works financial/test/ with regex ^financial/([^/]+)/?$ but if I try to switch test/financial to ([^/]+)/?$/^financial, it doesnt validate